# How can I copy styled pandas dataframes from Jupyter Notebooks to powerpoint without loss of formatting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, powerpoint

I am trying to copy styled pandas dataframes from Jupyter Notebooks to powerpoint without loss of formatting. I currently just take a screenshot to preserve formatting, but this is not ideal. Does anyone know of a better way? I search for an extension that maybe has a screenshot button, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

One way seems to be to copy the styled pandas table from jupyter notebook to excel. It will keep a lot of the formatting. Then you can copy it to powerpoint and it will maintain its style.

Answer (score 0):

Using the pandas styler object you can save directly to Excel. For example you can save the excel of your dataframe with the background color directly to Excel

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["City", "Temp (c)", "Rain (mm)", "Wind (m/s)"],
...                   data=[["Stockholm", 21.6, 5.0, 3.2],
...                         ["Oslo", 22.4, 13.3, 3.1],
...                         ["Copenhagen", 24.5, 0.0, 6.7]])
```

then:

```
>>> df.style.background_gradient(axis=None, low=0.75, high=1.0).to_excel("your_file.xlsx")
```